# Can't set static IP on systemd-networkd

Tags: ip, yocto, systemd-networkd

I can't set static IP on a wired interface using `systemd-networkd`. based on [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/systemd-networkd#Wired_adapter_using_a_static_IP), I should be able to set static IP using below code on `/etc/systemd/network/eth0.network` path:

```
[Match]
Name=enp1s0

[Address]
Address=10.1.10.9/24
Gateway=10.1.10.1
DNS=10.1.10.1
```

but I give below log from `systemd-networkd` service:

```
May 15 13:49:45 xxx systemd[1]: Stopped Network Service.
May 15 13:49:59 xxx systemd[1]: Starting Network Service...
May 15 13:50:00 xxx systemd-networkd[481]: /etc/systemd/network/eth0.network:6: Unknown key name 'DNS' in section 'Address', ignoring.
May 15 13:50:00 xxx systemd-networkd[481]: eth0: Gained IPv6LL
May 15 13:50:00 xxx systemd-networkd[481]: Enumeration completed
May 15 13:50:00 xxx systemd[1]: Started Network Service.
May 15 13:50:00 xxx systemd-networkd[481]: eth0: IPv6 successfully enabled
May 15 13:50:00 xxx systemd-networkd[481]: eth0: DHCPv4 address 192.168.0.230/24 via 192.168.0.254
May 15 13:50:12 xxx systemd-networkd[481]: eth0: Configured
```

you can find my hardware and software specification in below:

```
root@hostname:/etc/systemd/network# hostnamectl
   Static hostname: hostname
         Icon name: computer
        Machine ID: 
           Boot ID: 
  Operating System: NXP i.MX Release Distro 5.4-zeus (zeus)
            Kernel: Linux 4.1.15+
      Architecture: arm
```

Answer (score 1):

Your network device is called eth0:

```
May 15 13:50:00 xxx systemd-networkd[481]: eth0: IPv6 successfully enabled
```

but your rule only applies to interfaces named `enp1s0`:

```
[Match]
Name=enp1s0
```

This is covered in the arch wiki ([section [Match]](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/systemd-networkd#%5BMatch%5D)) and the man page systemd.networkd ([section [Match Section Options]](https://man.archlinux.org/man/systemd.network.5#%5BMATCH%5D_SECTION_OPTIONS)). The value of `Name` must match the device name, but `enp1s0` does not match `eth0`. You should change the rule to `Name=eth0`.